# create a table using distinct values from a column as the column names in a code

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net

I have a table like below figure with some distinct values. I'd like to create a new table with a column for each distinct value in R column, the column name would be started with S. Thanks in advance for your help. (in sql server or in c# or vb.net)

My Table:

```
Name Family R   C  D
---------------------
N1   F1     S1  1  A
N2   F2     S2  2  A
N3   F3     S1  1  B
N4   F4     S2  2  B
N5   F5     S3  3  A
```

New Table:

```
    S1  S2  S3 .......
---------------------------------
A   N1  N2  N5 .......
    F1  F2  F5 .......
----------------------------------
B   N3  N4
    F3  F4
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask]

Comment: Can you specify a problem which prevent you from creating required table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a pivot table like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Family", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("R", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("C", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("D", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"N1","F1","S1", 1, "A"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"N2","F2","S2", 2, "A"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"N3","F3","S1", 1, "B"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"N4","F4","S2", 2, "B"});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {"N5","F5","S3", 3, "A"});

            string[] uniqueRs = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>("R")).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

            DataTable pivot = new DataTable();
            pivot.Columns.Add("D", typeof(string));
            foreach (string uniqueR in uniqueRs)
            {
                pivot.Columns.Add(uniqueR, typeof(string));
            }

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("D"));

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                List<string> names = group.OrderBy(x => x.Field<int>("C")).Select(x => x.Field<string>("Name")).ToList();
                names.Insert(0, group.Key);
                pivot.Rows.Add(names.ToArray());

                List<string> families = group.OrderBy(x => x.Field<int>("C")).Select(x => x.Field<string>("Family")).ToList();
                families.Insert(0, group.Key);
                pivot.Rows.Add(families.ToArray());
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But you want what is the exact purpose of this requirement

Sample Data :

```
DECLARE @Table1  TABLE 
    (Name varchar(2), Family varchar(2), R varchar(2), C int, D varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Name, Family, R, C, D)
VALUES
    ('N1', 'F1', 'S1', 1, 'A'),
    ('N2', 'F2', 'S2', 2, 'A'),
    ('N3', 'F3', 'S1', 1, 'B'),
    ('N4', 'F4', 'S2', 2, 'B'),
    ('N5', 'F5', 'S3', 3, 'A')
;
```

Script

```
;with CTE as (
SELECT D,
[S1],
[S2],
[S3] 
        FROM (
select Name,
       Family, 
       R, 
       C, 
       D 
            FROM @Table1)t
                PIVOT (MAX(Name) For R in ([S1],[S2],[S3])
)pvt 
                GROUP BY  D,[S1],[S2],[S3] )
,
 CTE2 AS (

 SELECT D,
       [S1],
       [S2],
       [S3] 
         FROM (
select Name, 
       Family, 
       R, 
       C, 
       D FROM @Table1)t
            PIVOT (MAX(Family) For r in ([S1],[S2],[S3])
)pvt 
GROUP BY  D,[S1],[S2],[S3])

Select 
    CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN D ELSE NULL END NAME ,S1,S2,S3 FROM (
Select *,
        Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY D ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))RN from (
            SELECT  D,
            (SELECT S1 FROM cte where S1 IS NOT NULL AND C.D = D)S1,
            (SELECT S2 FROM cte where S2 IS NOT NULL AND C.D = D)S2,
            (SELECT S3 FROM cte where S3 IS NOT NULL AND C.D = D)S3  FROM  CTE C
            UNION 
            SELECT  D,
            (SELECT S1 FROM CTE2 where S1 IS NOT NULL AND C.D = D)S1,
            (SELECT S2 FROM CTE2 where S2 IS NOT NULL AND C.D = D)S2,
            (SELECT S3 FROM CTE2 where S3 IS NOT NULL AND C.D = D)S2  FROM cte2 C)T)TT
```